# jQuery append not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

```
 $('#buttonadd').click(function(){
            if ($counter < 10)
            {
                $counter++;
                $countonlyadd++;
                $('#buttondiv').append('<tr><td><select class="combo" name="combo'+$counter+'" style="width: 60px;" size="1"><option>UND</option><option>OHNE</option><option>ODER</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="textbox'+$counter+'" class="textbox" value="" /><a id="removetxt" class="removetxt" style="text-decoration: none;line-height: 3;" href="#">&nbsp;[X]</a></td></tr>');
            }else{
            }
            $('#send_count').val($countonlyadd);
        });
```

My code is not working in Internet Explorer, and i dont know why. All other browsers are ok but IE is not. He is not adding even 1 textbox.

Comment: Are you adding rows into a `div`, with no `table` wrapper?

Comment: no just named it with $ and no I#am not adding rows

Comment: it is kinda confusing, usually $xxx variables are for jQuery objects, not for Number types like he is using.

Comment: Well, it's **not** true that you're not trying to add rows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ya the problem is IE compatibility mode. This works fine in IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/NP9pG/3/ and firefox but when you switch to IE compatibility mode it doesn't work.

```
<div id="buttondiv">  </div>
<div id="send_count"></div>
<input type="button" id="buttonadd" value="add" />
```

but this http://jsfiddle.net/NP9pG/4/ will work fine tho in IE compatibility mode

```
<table id="buttondiv">  </table>
<div id="send_count"></div>
<input type="button" id="buttonadd" value="add" />
```

ya the problem is your html mark-up as suggested make the following change

```
<div id="buttondiv">
  <table id="tableData"></table>
</div>
```

rather append items to `table` instead of `div` element

therefore js code:

```
$('#tableData').append('<tr><td><select class="combo" name="combo'+$counter+'"  style="width: 60px;"  size="1"><option>UND</option><option>OHNE</option><option>ODER</option></select></td><td><input  type="text" name="textbox'+$counter+'"  class="textbox" value="" /><a id="removetxt" class="removetxt"  style="text-decoration: none;line-height: 3;"  href="#">&nbsp;[X]</a></td></tr>');
```

hope that helps

Comment: the point is i tried it and it is not appending anything in any browser then, so it#s a little tricky

Comment: have a look at this fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/NP9pG/4/ it works in firefox and IE

Comment: @Falk thanks mate, I'm glad i was able to assist. i work with IE a lot so i also come across these weird IE issues. but sometimes its a combination of both code and browser. anyway jsfiddler helps with pulling out these issues quite nicely. anyway good luck

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are adding a `tr` directly into which is not a valid html in any browser. Other browsers will not shout but IE will. Try this.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tnx9e/)**

**Markup change**

```
<div id="buttondiv">
   <table></table>
</div>
```

**JS change**

```
$('#buttonadd').click(function(){
            if ($counter < 10)
            {
                $counter++;
                $countonlyadd++;
                $('#buttondiv table').append('<tr><td><select class="combo" name="combo'+$counter+'" style="width: 60px;" size="1"><option>UND</option><option>OHNE</option><option>ODER</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="textbox'+$counter+'" class="textbox" value="" /><a id="removetxt" class="removetxt" style="text-decoration: none;line-height: 3;" href="#">&nbsp;[X]</a></td></tr>');
            }else{
            }
            $('#send_count').val($countonlyadd);
        });
```

Comment: You mean it is not appending in any browser?

Comment: Go into your favorite browser's development tools, Firebug, whatever, and look at the node structure that your code created.

Comment: in the fiddle it is working fine, but where is the point that is not working in the IE? I dont understand that, i will look if the HTML is wellformed

Answer (score 3):

It appears you're appending a single TR to a div, which may be your problem. You should append it to the TBODY of a TABLE instead.

Answer (score 0):

Questions are:

- Do you have $counter defined?
- Do you have $countonlyadd defined?
- Do you have <`table`> wrapper in #buttondiv ?

Think about these questions and if result is "no", that's the problem

If you have <`table`> wrapper, change

```
$('#buttondiv').
```

to

```
$('#buttondiv table').
```

Comment: but you don't have </table> wrapper ;)

Comment: Then consider appending to the table instead of the div directly.

Comment: "Then consider appending to the table instead of the div directly." => i will try it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps if you create the elements first..so create an object for your row, column, textbox, etc. And than append that into each other. Finally append the row to your div. Besides that, it is a bit weird to add a row to a div, and not to a table...